# Same application running with different speed in different cities using same database server?

Tags: vb6, sybase

I am using Sybase database in City A.
I made an application using VB6 which is working fine in City A.

Now same database is used in City B.But in this case my application working very slow.
Exe is placed on repective citi's local machine only and exes are also same.

What can be reason behind slow speed of same exe in City B ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with database access time.  The application itself isn't slow, but it's blocked waiting on database responses.

If you have an application that's perticularly "chatty," then database access will dominate the execution time, especially if the database is accessed over a relatively slow wide area network.

Assuming that the "fast" workstation is located in the same city as the database, the network access will be relatively fast, thus hiding any speed problems.  If you imagine the "slow" workstation being connected to the database via 56K modem, then think through what it's doing vis-a-vis the database, you may uncover the problem.

Questions to ask yourself:

- How many round trips does your application make to the database to perform its work?
- How long does a single DB round trip take?
- How much payload is involved with each DB round trip?

Comment: thanks for your answer.I am working on solution.let you know soon.